# background "see" padding on select box

Tags: css, forms

I have a form with a a select box that has a custom drop down arrow, put in place with the background property in my CSS. Right now it's positioned to the right, but that means it butts up right against the side of my box - is there some way I get get the arrow to "see" the padding to the right of it?

CSS:

```
select {
    background: url(images/contact/downarrow.svg) no-repeat right #f3f3f3;
}
```

RESULT: 
[image]

Comment: Use the `background-position` property to move it.

Comment: yeah, what I was doing wrong before was using pixels on the right/left value, but something like background: url(images/contact/downarrow.svg) no-repeat 96% #f3f3f3; works perfectly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For others:
if you use something like

```
background: url(images/contact/downarrow.svg) no-repeat 250px #f3f3f3;
```

that's going to (sensibly) just stick it 250px over, and when you resize the window it'll eventually be covered over by the shrinking screen size. To prevent this, replace those pixel values with percentages. Eg:

```
background: url(images/contact/downarrow.svg) no-repeat 96% #f3f3f3;
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can try to use a `<img src="images/contact/downarrow.svg" />`
with float: right;

And it will be nicely positioned to the right and will follow the Padding rules at your Tab area.

Good luck.